# Dynamically creating a Class and Enumerable object from MSSQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, system.reflection

I need to develop an ETL using C# that extracts a table from an MSSQL database, converts the specified table to .parquet format, and saves it in a specific location. I am using the Parquet.Net package and .Net4.5.

I have gotten the code to work on a single table, but need it to act more like a function. Where you would only need to update the database and table name and it will automatically build the required class, create the Enumerable object, and write the parquet.

```
//Create required class    
    public class SimpleStructure
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
//Import SQL table
    var table = new DataTable();
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM x", "Data Source=(x);Database=Test;" + "Integrated Security=x;"))
    {da.Fill(table);}

//Create Enumerable Object
        var results = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                      select new SimpleStructure
                      {
                          ID = row.Field<int>("ID"),
                          Text = row.Field<string>("Text")
                      };

//Write .parquet
            using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\"))
            {
                ParquetConvert.Serialize(results.ToArray(), stream);
            }
```

I need to figure out how to create the classes and enum objects dynamically as this script will need to be applied to 100s of tables. Any pointers would be helpful as I am fairly inexperienced with C#.

Comment: This is relatively easy, look into Reflection.Emit (e.g. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Of course, you also do not need to serialize Parquet with no classes at all, you can just use a plain old `SqlConnection` and `ExecuteReader` and then read row by row, and write row by row (which will give your app the best memory footprint)

Comment: You don't need DataTable or SqlDataAdapter to execute queries. Use a SqlCommand and ExecuteReader. Since Parquet is meant for big data, you shouldn't use `ToArray()` or load the data in memory. You should write the rows out to the file as they arrive

Comment: Thanks for all for the comments, I will try the suggested actions.